# I can I get similar end results to "protected" access of C# but in Swift?

Tags: swift, multithreading, protected

My goal is to write a class and have a function in it that contains code to run (in a run() function for example) in a background thread. Here are some requirements of my class (and related classes):

- Ensure that when I write the run() function, the code is guaranteed to run in a background thread without the programmer needing to know anything about threading and without having to remember to call any other code in that run() function related to the threading.
- Have a completion function function that is set elsewhere that is called when the background thread is finished its processing without the programmer having to write code in this run() function to make the call.
- Pretty much let someone derive a class from some base class and then write their background code in it in a run() function without writing anything else related to managing the background thread, completion function, etc.

Here's the code I might write in C#, in two DIFFERENT files:

```
class MyBase
{
    public Action completionFunction = NULL;
    public void begin()
    {
        RunInOtherThread( run ); // This function call is just pseudo-code for running that run() function in a background thread.
        if( completionFunction != Null )
            completionFunction();
    }
    virtual protected void run() = 0 // so this class cannot be instantiated
    {
    }
};
```

And in the other file:

```
class MySpecificClass : MyBase
{
    override void run()
    {
        // Do important stuff here!
    }
};
```

I do not know how to meet my requirements in Swift. They left out the "protected" level of protection for reasons that do not make sense to me (like thinking that I could not just fire a programmer that screwed up the code by exposing a base class protected function through a public function).

I am not familiar enough with some of the features of Swift to get these results. I do not need to have the classes work like the C# code even though it is a pretty good solution for me and my C# programmers.

How can I meet my requirements Swift?

BTW, I have seen Q&A about this with no reasonable way to fake the protected access level. I don't need to fake it, I just need another way to achieve the goal of hiding code in a derived class from all the world except for the base class, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) for this, rather than sub-classing. For example:

```
public protocol MyBase {
    // *** This requires any object that conforms to the protocol
    // *** to provide these, without specifying what they do
    var completionFunction: (() -> ())? {get set}
    func run() 
}
public extension MyBase {
    // *** This extension provides all objects that conform to the 
    // *** protocol with this function
    func begin() {
        RunInOtherThread( self.run ) // This function call is just pseudo-code for running that run() function in a background thread.
        if let c = self.completionFunction {
            c()
        }
    }
}

public class MySpecificClass: MyBase {
    // *** Now, rather than subclassing, we simply conform to the protocol 
    public var completionFunction: (() -> ())? = nil
    public func run() { 
        // *** No need to `override` - but *must* be supplied
        // Do important stuff here!
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that the run() function is public and therefore someone using MySpecificClass might call it instead of the begin function. Otherwise I can just implement my classes as they are but with the public run() function.

Comment: This is an excellent example of how to implement those classes in Swift aside from the public run() function. The protocol and extension are certainly a great way to handle the abstract base class issue. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidRector You could try giving the abstract base class `internal init()` and override it as `override public init()` in the concrete subclass. That should stop anyone instantiating the base class outside of the class hierarchy. It compiles, but can't test that it works in Playground. It doesn't, of course, force you to override `run()`, though, but you can make `run` `internal`...